# Why doesn't parameter type "Dict[str, Union[str, int]]" accept value of type "Dict[str, str]" (mypy)

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have a type for a dictionary of variables passed to a template:

```py
VariablesDict = Dict[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]
```

Basically, any dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are strings, numbers or None. I use this type in several template related functions.

Take this example function:

```py
def render_template(name: str, variables: VariablesDict):
    ...
```

Calling this function with a dictionary literal works fine:

```py
render_template("foo", {"key": "value"})
```

However, if I assign the dictionary to a variable first, like this:

```py
variables = {"key": "value"}

render_template("foo", variables)
```

Mypy gives an error:

> Argument 2 to "render_template" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Dict[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]"

It seems to me that any value of type `Dict[str, str]` should be safe to pass to a function that expects a parameter of type `Dict[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]`. Why doesn't that work by default? Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that `Dict` is mutable, and a function which accepts a `Dict[str, int|float|str|None]` could therefore reasonably insert any of those types into its argument.  If the argument was actually a `Dict[str, str]`, it now contains values that violate its type.  (For more on this, google "covariance/contravariance/invariance" and "Liskov Substitution Principle" -- as a general rule, mutable containers are invariant over their generic type[s].)

As long as `render_template` doesn't need to modify the dict you pass to it, an easy fix is to have it take a `Mapping` (which is an abstract supertype of `dict` that doesn't imply mutability, and is therefore covariant) instead of a `Dict`:

```
def render_template(name: str, variables: Mapping[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]):
    ...
```

Comment: Aah, of course, that makes total sense. I should probably be using `Mapping` rather than `Dict` for the majority of my function parameters...

Comment: Yup!  And the equivalent for `List` is `Sequence`.

Comment: "as a general rule, mutable containers are contravariant over their generic type" – Mutable containers are *invariant* over their generic type! The general rule is: if it goes in, it can be contravariant. If it comes out, it can be covariant. If it goes both in and out (as the elements of a mutable container do), it can only be invariant.

Comment: @Samwise Fortunately I'm already in the habit of using `Iterable[T]` rather than `List[T]` any time I need to loop through something :)

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to me that any value of type `Dict[str, str]` should be safe to pass to a function that expects a parameter of type `Dict[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]`.

Unfortunately, that assumption is wrong. Because `dict` is mutable, it *must* be *invariant* in its second type parameter.

> Why doesn't that work by default?

It doesn't work because it is not type-safe: `render_template` expects an argument of type `dict[str, Union[int, float, str, None]]`, which means that (among other things), it expects to be able to store an `int` in the `dict`.

However, you cannot store an `int` in a `dict[str, str]`, therefore MyPy rightfully rejects the code.

> Is there anything I can do to make this work?

The difference between the two snippets of code is that type inference in MyPy is *local*. Therefore, in the second example, MyPy does not take into account how the variable `variables` is used later on. It only infers its type from the assignment expression, and it tries to infer the *most strict type* possible.

Now, as I mentioned above, the problem is that `dict` is mutable. Therefore, if you can make it *immutable*, your code will work.

Thankfully, there is just the type for you: [`Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping). `Mapping`s are immutable, therefore, they can be *covariant* in their second type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One minor edit gets this to work:

```
variables: VariablesDict = {"key": "value"}
```

The [MyPy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance) list three solutions to the invariance problem:

1. Use an explicit type annotation (that is my answer shown above).
2. Make a copy of the right hand side (this is egregious).
3. Use immutable collections as annotations whenever possible: (that matches the excellent answer from @Samwise).

FWIW, the MyPy error message in this case is pretty good. It first gives the difference between the inferred type and the expected type, then it refers you to the relevant section of the docs, and lastly, it makes an appropriate suggestion:

```
tmp12.py:12: error: Argument 2 to "render_template" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "Dict[str, Union[int, float, st
r, None]]"
tmp12.py:12: note: "Dict" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
tmp12.py:12: note: Consider using "Mapping" instead, which is covariant in the value type
```

Comment: That's true, but that's a slightly less intuitive for my small pool of users, I had hoped this was fixable on my end. (There must be a better way! )