# Seems like a bug in Pylance type checking

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I got this weird error that `list[dict[str, str | int]]` cannot be assigned to `Sequence[dict[str, str | float | int] | None]`.

```
Argument of type "list[dict[str, str | int]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "params" of type "Sequence[dict[str, str | float | int] | None]" in function "batch_call"
  "list[dict[str, str | int]]" is incompatible with "Sequence[dict[str, str | float | int] | None]"
    TypeVar "_T_co@Sequence" is covariant
      Type "dict[str, str | int]" cannot be assigned to type "dict[str, str | float | int] | None"
        "dict[str, str | int]" is incompatible with "dict[str, str | float | int]"
          TypeVar "_VT@dict" is invariant
        Type cannot be assigned to type "None"
```

This makes no sense. The list is obviously a subset of the sequence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't parameter type "Dict\[str, Union\[str, int\]\]" accept value of type "Dict\[str, str\]" (mypy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603289/why-doesnt-parameter-type-dictstr-unionstr-int-accept-value-of-type-di)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually expected behavior, since `dict` is mutable.
Mypy provides a brief explanation of the issue in [its documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance).

Take a look at the following example:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

foo: list[dict[str, str | int]] = [{"foo": 2}]


def bar(s: Sequence[dict[str, str | float | int] | None]):
    d = s[0]
    if d:
        d["foo"] = 0.5


bar(foo)
```

The expression `bar(foo)` will modify `foo` by inserting a `float`, which violates the specified type of `foo`.