# Why nested MutableMappings are not compatible with Dicts?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

How come `MutableMapping[str, MutableMapping[str, Any]]` is not compatible with `dict[str, dict[str, Any]]` ?

For example:

```
def foo(value: MutableMapping[str, MutableMapping[str, Any]]) -> None:
    print(value)


value: dict[str, dict[str, Any]] = {}

foo(value)
```

And mypy displays this error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type
"Dict[str, Dict[str, Any]]"; expected "MutableMapping[str, MutableMapping[str, Any]]"  [arg-type]
    foo(value)
```

Comment: To confirm, `def foo(value: Mapping[str, MutableMapping[str, Any]])` works (so the problem is in variance during mutation).

Answer (score 2):

Okay I think I got it, thanks to comments and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603289/why-doesnt-parameter-type-dictstr-unionstr-int-accept-value-of-type-di?rq=2).

So while it is Mutable the `value` inside `foo` can be changed to any `MutableMapping` which might be not a `dict`. But outside `foo` the `value` accepts only `dict`s.

To simplify:

```
def foo(param: MutableMapping[str, str | int]) -> None:
    print(param)


value: dict[str, str] = {}

foo(value)
```

In this example inside `foo` you can put `int` into `param` (`param['key'] = 1`), and while it's Mutable it'll also affect `value` outside of `foo`, but `value` is defined with `dict[str, str]` without `int` support. And that breaks typing.